# how to get field type from lightning:inputField?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

i want to get field type of input field. Based on field type i want to validate fields. currently when i have boolean fields  in field set and i try to get value of that boolean field i cant get it using (getting values on onchange event of input field):

```
    event.getSource().get("v.fieldName") = event.getParam("value");
```

so , i need to use

```
    event.getParam("checked");
```

is there any way to get type of field so based on field type i can get values for  boolean field as well?

Updated :

Function which is being called :

**Markup code :**

```
<lightning:inputField  aura:id='inputFields' onchange="{!c.getInputValues}" fieldName="{!field.fieldName}" value=""/>
```

**js controller code :**

```
getInputValues : function(component, event, helper) {          
      contactDetails[event.getSource().get("v.fieldName")] = event.getParam("value");
 }
```

Comment: First - I don't think that `lightning:inputField` supports getting the type like you do. Second, to find the problem in your code -  try to refactor your code line: `var src = event.getSource();` see if it is not null, then take `var type = src.get("v.type");' then `alert(type);' .

Comment: there is no error in my code i am using solution given by one person but eventually he deleted his comment. Btw thanx for your suggestion.